# Accessing nested objects in EL

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, el

**I have this**

```
Class Output {
    HashMap<String,POC> hMap;
    //Other stuff
}
```

**and this**

```
Class POC {
    String var1;
    String var2;
    String var3;
    //Other stuff
}
```

**Basially, a hash map of objects...**

I am using Spring MVC framework and the above two classes are my model objects. My service class creates creates an output object, that it passes to the controller.

The controller returns that output object to the output.jsp after setting it as a model attribute called `output`

In the output.jsp page, I want to display however many items exist in the hashmap in the output object. For example, to display items stored in item1 (stored in HashMap as key1) this is what I've tried, with hard luck:

```
${output.hMap.key1.var1)
${output.hMap['key1'].var1)
```

None of it works the way I want it to. Please can anybody help me with this, or atleast suggest an alternative. Do share what you have in mind

**The solution:**
I feel stupid now. Both of the above work. The reason why I could not have them working, was because I did not initialize the POC with any values, before adding it into the hashMap.

Comment: What does `None of it works the way I want it to` mean? How do you add the object to your request/session/servlet context attributes?

Comment: I'm adding it using `model.addAttribute(...)`
I figured out the solution, and am updating it in the question itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide accessors for the fields you want to work with in EL.

```
public class Output {
    HashMap<String,POC> hMap;


    public HashMap<String, POC> getHMap() {
        return hMap;
    }

    public void setHMap(HashMap<String, POC> hMap) {
        this.hMap = hMap;
    }
}
```

Same goes for the attributes from the `POC` class.

Answer (score 0):

**The solution:** I feel stupid now. Both of the above work. The reason why I could not have them working, was because I did not initialize the POC with any values, before adding it into the hashMap.